# Log4s log format configuation

Tags: scala, logging

How do I configure how the format of the logging output?

E.g. the time format, thread name level etc.

How do I get the following?
17:15:00.154 Main INFO : Here is a log...

Answer (score 1):

[log4s](https://github.com/Log4s/log4s) is merely a wrapper for [slf4j](http://slf4j.org/). So its purpose is to provide a logging facade, not an implementation. You'll have to decide which actual logger implementation to use. A popular choice is logback, which you would configure using a logback.xml file. See http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping and http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html.